# How to validate View Model in MVC5 that is inherited?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a ViewModel

```
public class BaseFilter
{
    public virtual string Field1 { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? Field2 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Field3 { get; set; }
}


public class TestFilter : BaseFilter, IValidatableObject
{
    [Required]
    public override string Field3 { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext context)
    {
         // Validation logic..
    }
}
```

In my view I am using the TestFilter in a particular view.

```
@model MyReportSite.Models.TestFilter
```

However when I post in my view none of my validation is occurring.

How can I use validation (DataAtrributes and IValidatableObject) on an inherited ViewModel?

EDIT: To clarify in the controller I am seeing my ViewModel fields begin populated, but validation is missing. i.e. Required field not being enforced, etc...

Comment: When you say that there is no validation occurring, do you mean the Validate() method isn't being called?  If so, it's probably because the validation of one or more fields or the binding is failing.  The validation works in a few stages, calling the Validate() method on your `IValidatableObject`s depends on the binding and validation attributes passing the validation rules.

Comment: The Validate() method is not being called.  Also if I decorate the property in the inherited class with [Required] that is also being ignored.

Comment: Ok.  What data are you posting to your action?  Is it on a page with a field for `Field3`?  Is the field just being left empty and you're submitting the form?  Also, how are you verifying that the Required attribute on your property is being ignored?

Comment: The View loads and I do not enter any information in the field.  When I post to the controller the ModelState.IsValid = true.

Comment: If you add another attribute to it, such as `[MinLength(100)]` is that ignored too?  Also, are you binding to `TestFilter` in your controller action and not `BaseFilter`?

Comment: I set Field3 = "AAA" and when the View loaded I see AAA.  I added [Required] and [MinLength(100)] attributes to my derived class.  When I post it still post to the controller with a valid ModelState.

Comment: How peculiar!  Is it a new MVC project or an existing one?  The reason that I ask is that I wonder if there is a custom model validator that is preventing the attributes from being executed.  Using a model that is inheriting from another class doesn't prevent attributes from being executed in itself you see.  The only other thing I can think of is that you haven't defined your derived class in your action, it should be, for example `public ActionResult Index(TestFilter model)` and not your base class - because the base class doesn't have the attributes on it.

Comment: This is my own site. (First attempt at MVC)  So I know I'm not using a custom model validator.

Comment: Ok, and you're binding to your derived class in your action?

Comment: Yes I am setting the TestFilter and passing it to the view.

Comment: Yes, but you need to ensure that your action has the correct model defined, it doesn't matter what model you have defined in your view.  You could have `@model I.Like.FatherChristmas` defined in your view, however it's the model that you are binding to that is important in this case, it must be `TestFilter` and not `BaseFilter` :)

Comment: <Face plant>  That was it...

Comment: haha.  Yay!! :D  At least you found the issue.

Comment: Now I guess I have to create x amount of action methods just to consolidate it back into a common object for the next action method to use.

Comment: Post an answer so I can give you credit.  Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend having separate models, one for your binding and one that you use for your view (view model).  This way it keeps it very clear which properties are supposed to be posted back and which ones are on your view.  If you don't do that, things can become very unclear quite quickly when you start sharing the models between views and actions.  But that's just my preference.  Glad that it's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must refer to your *derived class* in your action result, as this is the model that will be constructed when the model binding occurs.  As you don't have any validation attributes on your base class, your attributes won't be executed during model binding.

```
public ActionResult Index(TestFilter model)
{
    // Correct, this model has validation attributes
}

public ActionResult Index(BaseFilter model)
{
    // Incorrect, your base model doesn't have validation attributes
}
```